# Java create JLabel with a custom method

Tags: java, swing, methods, jlabel

I want to create 26 similar JLabel, the only difference is location and text, so I want to do it with a method.
How can I create a JLabel with the name from a string?
I want to create a JLabel with the name from a string because if I use the same name for all JLabel, it will overwrite the previous JLabel that I create.
Here is what I have:

```
public void CreateButton(int x, int y, String text) {
    JLabel btnA = new JLabel("A");
    btnA.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Btn.png")));
    btnA.setSize(40, 40);
    btnA.setLocation(x, y);
    btnA.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
    btnA.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
    try {
        InputStream stream = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("MorePerfectDOSVGA.ttf");
        Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, stream).deriveFont(48f);
    } catch (IOException |FontFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    btnA.setFont(new Font("More Perfect DOS VGA", Font.PLAIN, 40));
    btnA.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    btnA.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
            btnA.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/BtnHover.png")));
            btnA.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
        }

        public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
            btnA.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Btn.png")));
            btnA.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        }

        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
            //Button Action
        }
    });
```

I want to use the String "text" from the CreateButton method to replace btnA and
JLabel content

Comment: where is your attempt?

Comment: welcome to SO. please show us what you have already written and elaborate a little on what your intent is, as it's hard to know what you really want from the little context you have provided

Comment: @LonelyNeuron edited my post

Comment: Seems like you should use an array instead of trying to dynamically create variable names (which doesn't work by the way).

Comment: thanks for the update. i still dont know what you mean by "How can I create a JLabel with the name from a string". What do you mean with "name"? i hope you are not talking about the variable name, are you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what your asking can't be done, or at least the way you seem to be thinking of.  You could use an array to store the newly created labels, or store them in a `Map`, but essentially, you need a factory method which can spit them out

```
public JLabel createButton(int x, int y, String text) {
    JLabel btnA = new JLabel("A");
    //...
    return btnA;
}
```

Then you can store them in array...

```
public class ... {
    //...
    private JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[26];
    //...

    protected void someMethodThatYouCall() {
        // Probably some kind of loop
        labels[indexOfNextLabel] = createButton(x, y, text);
    }
}
```

Or you can use some kind of `Map`

```
public class ... {
    //...
    private Map<JLabel> labels = new HashMap<JLabel>();
    //...

    protected void someMethodThatYouCall() {
        // Probably some kind of loop
        labels.put(text, createButton(x, y, text));
    }
}
```

IMHO, `JLabel` is a poor choice for what you seem to be trying to do.  Some kind of `JButton` would be a better choice, as they already have rollover support built in, as well as all the user interaction capabilities